# How can I start the process that doesn't die even after I close ssh?

Tags: ssh, unix

I am sshing to my remote CentOS 5 server and want to run a script that takes long time. 
How can I have it keep running even after I close ssh session?

Comment: Please search first, there are several answers to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a program such as [Screen](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/screen).

Start a screen with `Screen -S "name"`, resume it with `screen -x`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`nohup`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup) in conjunction with `&` like this:

```
nohup ./m_script.sh &
```

The magic of `nohup` is that it allows a process to run even if your connection to the machine is gone. Meaning you logged out or are even disconnected.  The `&` at the end means the process should run as a background process.

So when you enter that command the combo of `nohup` and `&` assures you that after you logout the process will still be running on the server.